# error in "Non-ROS Installation" of ROSJAVA

Tags: ros, installation, git, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the instruction here   rosjava.github.io/rosjava_core/latest/installing.html
and I failed at this command line at Non-ROS installation :

git checkout -b hydro origin/hydro

the error is:
Fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories) .git

Can anybody help me with this?
I just want to set up the developing environment of rosjava for Android.
I have installed ROS hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106276/error-in-%22non-ros-installation%22-of-rosjava/) by [Lunbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/9381/lunbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2013-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation is missing one step. The sequence should be:

```
git clone <censored*>://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core
cd rosjava_core
git checkout -b hydro origin/hydro
```

- Removed the 'https' prefix from the url to avoid display problems.

---

Originally posted by [drmorbius](https://answers.ros.org/users/9611/drmorbius/) with karma: 26 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-12-07**:
Bugfixed the docs...thanks.